# What is the easy and effective way to learn in tandem live, when speaker A has B1 and speaker B barely has A1 in the language of A speaker?

Tags: learning-methods, german, russian, language-exchange

I learn German (~B1), my friend learns Russian (~A1, just a little bit of the vocabulary and ability to pronounce the text). Mainly we communicate through English. Next couple weeks we live together, so I am trying to find what are the the most effective methods to learn in a pair. I guess, one of the criteria is "fun", because it's hard for us sometimes to learn grammar for a long time.

Comment: So you are a native speaker of Russian and your tandem partner is a native speaker of German?